# How can I show all input and output with Expect.pm (Perl)?

Tags: perl, stdout, expect

Here is a little Perl server.  It displays (1), accepts a line of input, then displays (2), etc.  If you type "error" or "commit", it gives a custom message.  If you type "exit", it quits.  Otherwise, it just endlessly takes lines of input.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
$|++;

my $counter = 1;
print "($counter) ";

while (<STDIN>) {
  chomp;
  if ($_ eq "error")  {print "Error on command #$counter\n";}
  if ($_ eq "commit") {print "Committing data\n";}
  if ($_ eq "exit")   {print "Exiting program...\n"; exit;}

  $counter++;
  print "($counter) ";
}
```

Now, here is an Expect.pm client script to interact with the server script by typing in various lines.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Expect;
$|++;

my $exp = new Expect;
$exp->raw_pty(1);
$exp->log_file("/tmp/expect.out");
$exp->log_stdout(1);

my @commands = (
  "This is the first command",
  "Here is the second command",
  "error",
  "commit",
  "This is the last command",
  "exit",
);


$exp->spawn("./expecttest_server.pl");
foreach my $command (@commands) {
  print "$command\n";
  $exp->send("$command\n");
  $exp->expect(1, '-re','\(\d+\)');
}
$exp->soft_close();
```

What I want is to be able to store the entire session from start to finish, including everything the server script generated, and everything the Expect.pm script sent.

That is, I **want** my client script to be able to return output like this, which is what you would see if you ran and interacted with the server script manually:

```
(1) This is the first command
(2) Here is the second command
(3) error
Error on command #3
(4) commit
Committing data
(5) This is the last command
(6) exit
Exiting program...
```

But the STDOUT display that comes from running the client script looks like this:

```
This is the first command
(1) (2) Here is the second command
error
(3) Error on command #3
(4) commit
This is the last command
Committing data
(5) (6) exit
Exiting program...
```

and the file specified by $exp->log_file (tmp/expect.out) shows this:

```
(1) (2) (3) Error on command #3
(4) Committing data
(5) (6) Exiting program...
```

I've tried experimenting by logging various combinations of the command itself + the **before_match** and **after_match** variables returned by $exp->expect().  But so far I haven't gotten the right combination.  And it seems like an awfully clunky way to get what I'm looking for.

So, what's the best practice for capturing the entirety of an Expect.pm session?

Thanks to anyone who can help!

Comment: Why would you expect to get `(1) This is the first command` when you print `This is the first command` to `STDOUT` *before* you send it to your server program? The output you get is exactly what I would expect (pun not intended).

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: if it was simply a matter of prepending the first command to an output variable or file, that would be easy enough.  The trickier issue is that neither STDOUT or the $exp->log_file contains the data formatted that way that it would actually appear if you interacted with the program yourself.  The block labeled "It should look like this" is what I can't figure out how to reconstruct in my client script.

Comment: So by "It **should** look like this," I guess you mean, "I **want** it to look like this."

Comment: Why not just `print "($counter) $_";` in your server?

Comment: [Crosspost](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1103014).

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: Correct - that is what I want it to look like.  I'll reword the OP for clarity.  The server script is actually a simplified, generalized example of something I do not have control over.  It may be a Linux script, Cisco router, Gigamon node, etc. So for this example, I can't modify what the server script outputs.  All I can hope to do is take the "I want it to look like this" block (which is what you'd see if you interacted with the server script manually) and try to produce that same output within the client script after the Expect process has run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When run on the command line, your server prints

```
(1)
```

to stdout immediately and waits for input.

However, when you create an `Expect` object, you are actually setting up a PTY (a pseudo terminal). Any processes you `spawn` will have their stdin and stdout connected to this PTY, *not* to the TTY that your shell is connected to. This means that it's up to your `Expect` object whether output from the spawned process is displayed or not; it will not be displayed automatically.

When you `spawn` a process, the `Expect` object holds onto any output in an input buffer. When you `send` a string to the process, any additional output that is generated will be read into the buffer. If the PTY has echoing enabled (the default), the string you send will be echoed back, but the contents of the `Expect` object's buffer will not.

When you call the `expect` method, Expect waits until a matching string appears in the input buffer. If a match is found before the timeout expires, `expect` returns and prints the matching string.

So, all you need to do is call `expect` *before* `send`ing your first command, something like this:

#### Server

```
use strict;
use warnings;

$| = 1;

my $counter = 1;
do {
    print "($counter) ";
    $counter++;
} while (<>);
```

#### Client

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Expect;

$| = 1;

my $exp = Expect->new;

my $server = './expect_server';
$exp->spawn($server);

my @commands = qw(foo bar baz);

foreach my $command (@commands) {
    $exp->expect(1, '-re', '\(\d+\)');
    $exp->send("$command\r");
}
$exp->soft_close;
```

#### Output

```
(1) foo
(2) bar
(3) baz
(4)
```

Note that this is the exact same process you would use when interacting with a process manually: wait for the prompt, then type your command.